# Text Box Event Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a noobie and I need some help with changing events in textbox.

Here's the code I am working with:

```
    <body>
      <form action="#">
        <input type="text" id="begin" /> Apple
        =
        <input type="text" id="done" /> 


        <select id="newValue" onchange = "function()">
          <option value="a">Apple</option>
          <option value="b">Blueberry</option>
          <option value="c">Cheese</option>
        </select>
        <p id = "weight"></p>
      </form>

      <script>
      var apple = document.getElementById('begin'),
          choice = document.getElementById('done');

      apple.onkeyup = function(){
         var temp = document.getElementById("newValue").value;
          choice.value = this.value * 1; //if apple
         choice.value = this.value * 2; //if blueberry
         choice.value = this.value * 3; //if cheese
      }
</script>
</body>
```

I have two text boxes. The left text box ('begin') will accept the weight of apple. But the right box ('done') should change the number value depending on what the user chooses form the drop-down text list.
My

```
apple.onkeyup = function(){
```

is not doing the right thing. If I give the value of '2' to the left text box,no matter what I choose in the dropdown list, it will return 2 * 3 = 6, meaning it skips everything in the function and evaluates only the last statement.

```
choice.value = this.value * 3; /*if cheese
```

How I want it to work is:

```
Left Box : 2      Right Box : 2 (if apple was chosen)
Left Box : 2      Right Box : 4 (if blueberry was chosen)
```

I'm sure I need a few 'if statements' to determine which output choice was chosen, something along the lines of

```
    if(temp = Apple){
       choice.value = this.value * 1;
    }else if(temp = Blueberry){
       choice.value = this.value * 2;
    }
   }
```

The value in Right Box  should also change as the user chooses a different item from the list..

Although I'm not sure if that's the right approach/syntax.

Comment: *"Left Box : 2      Right Box : 2 (if apple was chosen)"*. You're missing the 'if' thing in your code

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira hi, I edited my post with a if-else statement. Would you mind looking at that please? After adding the if-else statement in my code, the right value doesn't even show up anymore, so I'm sur ethe way I'm writing the 'if' is wrong. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two Text Box Events Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28424466/two-text-box-events-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be what you are looking for, [here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3opypnyf/).

Remove the `onchange` from your `newValue` selection and set it in your JavaScript, just like you are doing with your `onkeyup` function for `apple`. In your code above, your are calling `function()` which will likely just cause errors. `function()` represents an anonymous function, you need to name your function with the syntax `function name()` if you'd like to call it in this way. However, since you are already setting `onkeyup` from your JavaScript, you might as well set `onchange` from the same place in this case.

Then change your JavaScript to this:

```
var apple = document.getElementById("begin"),
    choice = document.getElementById("done"),
    fruits = document.getElementById("newValue");

// This function properly sets the done field.
var setDone = function() {
    var newVal = document.getElementById("newValue").value;
    if (newVal == "a") {
        choice.value = apple.value * 1; //if apple
    } else if (newVal == "b") {
        choice.value = apple.value * 2; //if blueberry
    } else if (newVal == "c") {
        choice.value = apple.value * 3; //if cheese
    } else {
        alert("I couldn't find that value!");
    }
}

apple.onkeyup = setDone;
fruits.onchange = setDone;
```

I made your anonymous function into a named variable ,added if statements to check for the value of `newValue` and set the value of `apple` appropriately.

Then I set the `onkeyup` and `onchange` events for `apple` and the new variable I created for your selector, `fruits`.

If you have any questions about how any of this works, feel free to ask in the comments below.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Since I have this implementation down, I was wondering if you could assist me with implementing a set-up with two text boxes...
I would like to make something like this:
Left Box : 2  [Apple] = Right Box : 6 [Cheese]
Left Box : 2 [Blueberry] = Right Box : 1 [Apple]

I tried adding on to the implementation above, but only one of the values would change...if you can provide me with a fiddle that'd be great! 
Thank you (:

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you're asking from that comment... I provided a fiddle at the top of my response. Try it out, and let me know if that's what you're trying to accomplish, or if there are still issues with how it is working. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this - I'm not sure if I got my apples and blueberries in the right order, but it looks to work OK:

```
var apple = document.getElementById('begin'),
          choice = document.getElementById('done');

      apple.onkeyup = function(){
         var temp = document.getElementById("newValue").value;
          if (temp == 'a') {
          choice.value = this.value * 1;
          } 
          if (temp == 'b') {
         choice.value = this.value * 2;
          }
          if (temp == 'c') {
         choice.value = this.value * 3; 
          }
      }
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cxoojt0n/)

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping. Actually I have that in my code already, after posting the question. But the main trouble I have right now is to have the second text box update the value as I choose a different item from the dropdown list....thanks...

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm going to recreate some stuff here. From what I can tell, you want to select a food item and output its weight in the other text field.

```
/* begin and done are input and output. */
var input=document.getElementById("input");
var output=document.getElementById("output");

/* Handles a change in the input text field, like if the user types apple, blueberry, etc. */
/* You could make this a keyup listener as well, I suppose. */
input.addEventListener("change",function(event_){
    switch(this.value){
        case "apple":
            output.value="weight of apple";
        break;
        case "blueberry":
            output.value="weight of blueberry";
        break;
        /* Optional default value for when the user is messing around. */
        default:
            output.value="Please select an item from the drop down list."
        break;
    }
});
```

Be sure to use conditionals to evaluate your output. I used a switch statement, but if statements are great, too! What I mean is this:

```
var x=10;
x=15;
x=7;
alert(x);// Returns 7

var y=Math.random()*100;
if (y<50){
    alert("y is less than 50");
} else {
    alert("y is greater than 50");
}
```

Multiple assignments in a row will be overwritten by subsequent assignments.

Answer (score 0):

Your code :

```
var temp = document.getElementById("newValue").value;
choice.value = this.value * 1; //if apple
choice.value = this.value * 2; //if blueberry
choice.value = this.value * 3; /*if cheese
```

is equal to :

```
var temp = document.getElementById("newValue").value; 
choice.value = this.value * 3;
```

you repeat assign value to choice.value, so the finally result is :

```
choice.value = this.value * 3;
```

you should change the code :

```
<select id="newValue" onchange = "function()">
      <option value="1">Apple</option>
      <option value="2">Blueberry</option>
      <option value="3">Cheese</option>
    </select>
```

to :

```
<select id="newValue" onchange = "function()">
      <option value="a">Apple</option>
      <option value="b">Blueberry</option>
      <option value="c">Cheese</option>
    </select>
```

and then change the code :

```
var temp = document.getElementById("newValue").value;
choice.value = this.value * 1; //if apple
choice.value = this.value * 2; //if blueberry
choice.value = this.value * 3; /*if cheese
```

to the code :

```
var temp = document.getElementById("newValue").value;
choice.value = this.value * temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, I tested which can be work.

```
<body>
  <form action="#">
    <input type="text" id="begin" /> Apple
    =
    <input type="text" id="done" /> 


    <select id="newValue" onchange = "f();">
      <option value="1">Apple</option>
      <option value="2">Blueberry</option>
      <option value="3">Cheese</option>
    </select>
    <p id = "weight"></p>
  </form>

  <script>
  var weightTag = document.getElementById('begin');
  var totalTag = document.getElementById('done');

  function f(){
    var priceTag = document.getElementById('newValue');
    if (weightTag.value != "") {
        var index = priceTag.selectedIndex;
        var priceValue = priceTag.options[index].value;
        totalTag.value = weightTag.value * priceValue;
    }

  }

  weightTag.onkeyup = f;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need.

```
  <html>
            <head>

            </head>
                <body>
              <form action="#">
                <input type="text" id="begin" onkeyup="k(1);" /> 
                    <select id="Fruitbox1" onclick="k(1);">
                        <option value = "3">Apple</option>
                        <option value = "1.5">Blueberry</option>
                        <option value = "1">Cherry</option>
                </select>

                =

                <input type="text" id="done"  onkeyup="k(0);"/> 
                    <select id="Fruitbox2" onclick="k(0);">
                        <option

 value="3">Apple</option>
                    <option value="1.5">Blueberry</option>
                    <option value="1">Cherry</option>
                </select>
            <p id = "leftWeight"></p>
            <p id = "rightWeight"></p>
          </form>
         <script>


            function k(x){

                            var weightOfFruit1=document.getElementById("Fruitbox1")
                            var weightOfFruit2=document.getElementById("Fruitbox2")
                            var NumberofFruit1=document.getElementById("begin")
                            var NumberofFruit2=document.getElementById("done")
                            if(x==1)
                            {
                                TotalNumberofFruit2=(NumberofFruit1.value * weightOfFruit1.value)/weightOfFruit2.value
                                NumberofFruit2.value=parseInt(TotalNumberofFruit2)
                            }else
                            {   
                                TotalNumberofFruit1=(NumberofFruit2.value * weightOfFruit2.value)/weightOfFruit1.value
                                NumberofFruit1.value=parseInt(TotalNumberofFruit1)
                            }


            }

           </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```