# Two Text Box Events Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a little bit of trouble writing a two-textbox-event and would like some help...

I have the following:

```
<body>
   <form action="#">
      <input type="text" id="begin" /> 
      <select id "toLeftBox">
         <option value = "a">Apple</option>
         <option value = "b">Blueberry</option>
         <option value = "c">Cherry</option>
      </select>
      =
      <input type="text" id="done" /> 
      <select id= "toRightBox">
         <option value="a">Apple</option>
         <option value="b">Blueberry</option>
         <option value="c">Cherry</option>
      </select>
      <p id = "leftWeight"></p>
      <p id = "rightWeight"></p>
   </form>
   <script>
      var lftchoice = document.getElementById('begin'),
          rgtchoice = document.getElementById('done');
          newLeft   = document.getElementById("toLeftBox");
          newRight  = document.getElementById("toRightBox");

      newValRight = function(){
         var tempR = document.getElementById("toRightBox").value;
          if(tempR == "a"){
            rgtchoice.value = lftchoice.value * 1;
          }else if(tempR == "b"){
            rgtchoice.value = lftchoice.value * 2;
          }else if(tempR == "c"){
            rgtchoice.value = lftchoice.value * 3;
          }
       }
       newValLeft = function(){
         var tempL = document.getElementById("toLeftBox").value;
         if(tempL == tempR){
           lftchoice.value = rgtchoice.value*1;
         }else if(tempL == "b"){
           lftchoice.value = rghtchoice.value * 2;
         }else if(tempL == "c"){
           lftchoice.value = rgtchoice.value * 3;
         }
       }
         lftchoice.onkeyup = newValRight;
         rgtchoice.onkeyup = newValLeft;
         newLeft.onchange = newValLeft;
         newRight.onchange = newValRight;
   </script>
</body>
```

I have two text boxes. The left text box ('begin') will accept the weight of 'chosen item'. But the right box ('done') should change the number value depending on what the user chooses form the drop-down text list.
When the value is entered in the left box, the right box updates correctly, while changing items in drop down list.
However, I would like it to work both ways.
For example:

```
Left 23 [Apple] = Right 23 [Apple]
Left 23 [Apple] = Right 46 [Blueberry] (if I change to blueberry on right list)
Left 46 [Blueberry] = Right 46 [Blueberry] (if I keep the right, and just change lft list)
```

Simply put, I would like both text boxes to update to the correct value with respect to the chosen fruit/ equivalence on the opposite box.

thank you

Comment: is it newValue or toRightBox? <select id="newValue" toRightBox">

Comment: @AbhilashCherukat it is "toRightBox" 
sorry. I have made the appropriate changes in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have made several syntax errors in your code and have tried to access some variables which are out of scope. You have also made typos in variable names.

A working fiddle of your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1twyp4os/4/)

The html code

```
<form action="#">
    <input type="text" id="begin" /> 
    <select id="toLeftBox">
      <option value = "a">Apple</option>
      <option value = "b">Blueberry</option>
      <option value = "c">Cherry</option>
    </select>

    =

    <input type="text" id="done" /> 
    <select id="toRightBox">
      <option value="a">Apple</option>
      <option value="b">Blueberry</option>
      <option value="c">Cherry</option>
    </select>
    <p id = "leftWeight"></p>
    <p id = "rightWeight"></p>
  </form>
```

The javascript

```
var lftchoice = document.getElementById('begin'),
      rgtchoice = document.getElementById('done'),
      newLeft   = document.getElementById("toLeftBox"),
      newRight  = document.getElementById("toRightBox");
    var tempL;
   var tempR;
  newValRight = function(){
      tempR = document.getElementById("toRightBox").value;
      if(tempR == "a"){
        rgtchoice.value = lftchoice.value * 1;
      }else if(tempR == "b"){
        rgtchoice.value = lftchoice.value * 2;
      }else if(tempR == "c"){
        rgtchoice.value = lftchoice.value * 3;
      }
   }

   newValLeft = function(){
     tempL = document.getElementById("toLeftBox").value;
     if(tempL == tempR){
       lftchoice.value = rgtchoice.value*1;
     }else if(tempL == "b"){
       lftchoice.value = rgtchoice.value * 2;
     }else if(tempL == "c"){
       lftchoice.value = rgtchoice.value * 3;
     }
   }
     lftchoice.onkeyup = newValRight;
     rgtchoice.onkeyup = newValLeft;
     newLeft.onchange = newValLeft;
     newRight.onchange = newValRight;
```

Comment: There are logical errors in this code. But the code runs :)

Comment: @AbhilashCherukat I know there are logical errors. I just wanted to point out the errors in the user's code and leave the logic to the user.

Comment: That i will appreciate anytime :D

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you need.

```
        <body>
      <form action="#">
        <input type="text" id="begin" onkeyup="k(1);" /> 
            <select id="Fruitbox1" onclick="k(1);">
                <option value = "3">Apple</option>
                <option value = "1.5">Blueberry</option>
                <option value = "1">Cherry</option>
        </select>

        =

        <input type="text" id="done"  onkeyup="k(0);"/> 
            <select id="Fruitbox2" onclick="k(0);">
                <option value="3">Apple</option>
                <option value="1.5">Blueberry</option>
                <option value="1">Cherry</option>
            </select>
        <p id = "leftWeight"></p>
        <p id = "rightWeight"></p>
      </form>
     <script>


        function k(x){

                        var weightOfFruit1=document.getElementById("Fruitbox1")
                        var weightOfFruit2=document.getElementById("Fruitbox2")
                        var NumberofFruit1=document.getElementById("begin")
                        var NumberofFruit2=document.getElementById("done")
                        if(x==1)
                        {
                            TotalNumberofFruit2=(NumberofFruit1.value * weightOfFruit1.value)/weightOfFruit2.value
                            NumberofFruit2.value=parseInt(TotalNumberofFruit2)
                        }else
                        {   
                            TotalNumberofFruit1=(NumberofFruit2.value * weightOfFruit2.value)/weightOfFruit1.value
                            NumberofFruit1.value=parseInt(TotalNumberofFruit1)
                        }


        }

       </script>
</body>
```